# Gitosis and ssh keys - does the email address have anything to do with the git email address?

Tags: git, ssh, gitosis, ssh-keys

I'm trying to set up gitosis on a server. I was just wondering one thing, my ssh key has my gmail address at the end, because I was originally using it for github. For this new project on the server I'm setting up, I want to use my email address for this organization when committing to git. Is it OK for me to use the same ssh key when setting it up in gitosis, or will I need to use a different ssh key generated on my account `me@newserver`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope... the only thing that matters is that the private key matches with the user. The names and email just pair the SSH Key up with a user because you commit as git@your-domain.com.

Comment: Cool, that's what I was expecting. Thanks for the quick response!